# Make datetime derived from one column

Tags: r

I want to create a new column datetime that contains the recorded date-times, derived from the path. The path column is formed like (`data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-05-14.csv`), and I need to make a `dttm` column which make path column became (`2017-03-09 05:14:00` ) How can I do it?
The path column looks like

```
#> # A tibble: 43,793 x 5
#>    path                   delay stop.id stop.sequence route           
#>    <chr>                  <dbl>   <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>           
#>  1 data/aklbus2017/2017-…   150    5050            28 15401-201702141…
#>  2 data/aklbus2017/2017-…    97    3093             6 83401-201702141…
#>  3 data/aklbus2017/2017-…    50    4810            13 98105-201702141…
#>  4 data/aklbus2017/2017-…    58    6838             5 36201-201702141…
#>  5 data/aklbus2017/2017-…  -186    2745            11 37301-201702141…
#>  6 data/aklbus2017/2017-…   183    2635            14 03301-201702141…
#>  7 data/aklbus2017/2017-…  -144    3360             4 10001-201702141…
#>  8 data/aklbus2017/2017-…  -151    2206            20 38011-201702141…
#>  9 data/aklbus2017/2017-…   -46    2419            38 38011-201702141…
#> 10 data/aklbus2017/2017-…  -513    6906            42 38012-201702141…
#> # … with 43,783 more rows
```

which i want is

```
#> # A tibble: 43,793 x 5
#>    datetime            delay stop.id stop.sequence route
#>    <dttm>              <dbl>   <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>
#>  1 2017-03-09 05:14:00   150    5050            28 15401
#>  2 2017-03-09 05:14:00    97    3093             6 83401
#>  3 2017-03-09 05:14:00    50    4810            13 98105
#>  4 2017-03-09 05:14:00    58    6838             5 36201
#>  5 2017-03-09 05:14:00  -186    2745            11 37301
#>  6 2017-03-09 05:14:00   183    2635            14 03301
#>  7 2017-03-09 05:14:00  -144    3360             4 10001
#>  8 2017-03-09 05:14:00  -151    2206            20 38011
#>  9 2017-03-09 05:14:00   -46    2419            38 38011
#> 10 2017-03-09 05:14:00  -513    6906            42 38012
#> # … with 43,783 more rows
```

Comment: Using `dput(head(yourdata))` ensures that solvers can just copy the code and make data that is exactly the same as yours and therefore eliminate the risk that they are using the wrong data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `parse_date_time` function from lubridate after
we used `str_sub` from `stringr`package

```
# Example data
df <- tribble(
  ~path,
  "data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-05-14.csv",
  "data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-06-14.csv",
  "data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-07-14.csv",
  "data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-08-14.csv",
  "data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-09-14.csv",
)

# The code:
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(datetime = parse_date_time(str_sub(path, start=17, end = 32), "ymd_hm"))
```

Output:

```
  path                                 datetime           
  <chr>                                <dttm>             
1 data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-05-14.csv 2017-03-09 05:14:00
2 data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-06-14.csv 2017-03-09 06:14:00
3 data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-07-14.csv 2017-03-09 07:14:00
4 data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-08-14.csv 2017-03-09 08:14:00
5 data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-09-14.csv 2017-03-09 09:14:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `basename` and `tools::file_name_sans_ext`

```
library(tools)
df <- data.frame(path=c('data/abc/2017-03-09-05-14.csv','data/xyz/2017-03-10-05-14.csv'))
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(df$path)), format="%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M",tz='UTC')

df

                           path            datetime
1 data/abc/2017-03-09-05-14.csv 2017-03-09 05:14:00
2 data/xyz/2017-03-09-05-14.csv 2017-03-09 05:14:00
```

Answer (score 0):

With a view to these problems, read up on how to work with strings. There are many ways to break up strings in parts, replace parts and/or reassemble them differently.

Using the `{tidyverse}`, you can do the following.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate) # for time parsing - ymd_hms()

#-------- the data
df <- data.frame(path = "data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-05-14.csv") %>% 
#--------- tidyr to break up path into new columns
    separate( col  = path
             ,into = c("folder","sub-folder","file")
             , sep = "/"
            ) %>% 
#----------- string operation
mutate( dttm  = str_remove(string = file, pattern = ".csv")
      , dttm2 = ymd_hm(dttm) )
```

This gives you:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ folder    : chr "data"
 $ sub-folder: chr "aklbus2017"
 $ file      : chr "2017-03-09-05-14.csv"
 $ dttm      : chr "2017-03-09-05-14"
 $ dttm2     : POSIXct, format: "2017-03-09 05:14:00"
```

There is no need to keep all columns. You can combine the string operation into one `mutate()` call. I just put it here to give you an idea on how to "step" through a series of steps to handle your string problem.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(stringr)
library(rebus)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rebus'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stringr':
#> 
#>     regex
library(tidyverse)
library(chron)

datetime <- 
    c('data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-05-14.csv',
      'data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-05-15.csv',
      'data/aklbus2017/2017-03-09-05-16.csv')

date_separated <- 
    str_match(datetime, '2017/' %R% capture('.*') %R% '\\.csv$')[, 2] %>% 
    str_match(capture(one_or_more(DGT) %R% '-' %R% one_or_more(DGT) %R% '-' %R% one_or_more(DGT)) %R% '-' %R% capture('.*$')) %>% 
    `[`(, 2:3) 

date_separated
#>      [,1]         [,2]   
#> [1,] "2017-03-09" "05-14"
#> [2,] "2017-03-09" "05-15"
#> [3,] "2017-03-09" "05-16"

date_separated[, 2] <- date_separated[, 2] %>% str_replace('-', ':') %>% str_c(':00') 

chron(dates=date_separated[,1],times=date_separated[,2],format=c('y-m-d','h:m:s')) %>% as.POSIXct() %>% tibble(datetime = .)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   datetime           
#>   <dttm>             
#> 1 2017-03-09 02:14:00
#> 2 2017-03-09 02:15:00
#> 3 2017-03-09 02:16:00

#bind_cols(datetime, data)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>